# Using qunit/protractor/casper to run integration tests against remote site

Tags: integration-testing, protractor, ember-cli, casperjs, qunit

How can one set up qunit to run integration tests against a remote site? I've used ember-cli test runner which has qunit + testem built in to run interation tests locally in an ember-cli project. How it does this, is to load the entire ember app in the qunit container then run the tests which can be unit or integration tests. This approach is also good if I can't have a JRE dependancy.

I think it may be possible to be able to load fooDomain.com/somepath in an iframe and then run the tests against it.

Has anyone a workflow for this?

Comment: qunit has nothing to do with protractor or integration testing.

Comment: @NickTomlin it is used for integration testing in all ember projects.